# How to do self hosting in ASP.net 5 Application?

Tags: asp.net-core

I read some where that with HTTP.sys we can self host asp.net 5 applications. What does that mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HTTP.sys` is the `Windows HTTP Protocole stack`.It's [a part of IIS](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/introduction-to-iis/introduction-to-iis-architecture).
You can self host an `ASP.Net 5` application by running the `web` command. it will use `HTTP.sys`.

**project.json**

```
...
 "commands": {
    /* Change the port number when you are self hosting this application */
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls http://localhost:5000",
     ...
 }
```

To run the self hosted project in a console:

```
$ dnx . web
```